# What is this pale green spiky caterpillar found in Athens, Greece?

Tags: identification, caterpillar

[image]I found this caterpillar on my balcony in Athens, Greece. It's growing quite fast, eating about a leaf per day, choosing new baby leaves.

Please let me know what it is!  Does it turn to a butterfly or moth?

[image: Found this caterpillar on my balcony, please let me know what it is!!]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is probably a geometer moth relative because it seems to have only two pairs of prolegs rather than the usual five.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometer_moth

Note that not all moths are necessarily ugly or poisonous.

Comment: It is growing rapidly, and almost getting a green hue to it's body!